# Purpose of i18n library

Tags: web, internationalization

Maybe this question is a bit silly. I have no ideas the purpose of using i18n library since browser can display any languages. Can someone explain? see this example

http://jsbin.com/wukum/2/

Comment: Do you *write* strings and region-specific data in code in all languages and for all regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: for not to write strings in all languages in your code.
Say, you have a web application and want to translate it into 20 languages. What will you do then? I hope you don't want to do stupid things like this:

```
// lang is the language detected from the user's browser or in any other way
if (lang == 'en') {
    alert("Hello world!");
} else if (lang == 'fr') {
    alert("Salut monde!");
}
```

and so on, and so forth.
That's why you need a decent i18n library that would separate your code from the translations.
P.S. And, btw, translators are not always good at developing, they might easily get scared of the code itself, so you have to provide them with something they can work with.